# Django: Use model field value as valid template tag in html template

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a part on my site where an admin user can create new widget which display in the sidebar on the homepage. I would like to allow users to input code into the form and have the code act as valid code within the template instead of just text. I can't find anything on stack overflow and google which talks about this. So far I have the form and template setup which allows users to add widgets however it is displayed in the page rendering is text instead of executing it as code. Here is what I have so far and what it is doing, I think you'll be able to see what I'm going for based on the code that is being displayed as standard text.

Adminpanel app models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Widget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    widget_order = models.IntegerField(blank=False,unique=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Adminpanel app widget_list_inner.html template:

```
{% for widget in widget_list %}
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-content">
            <p>{{ widget.body }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Adminpanel app widget_form.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="colorset-base">
        <h2>Create new widget</h2>
        <form id="postForm" action="{% url 'adminpanel:create-widget' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary btn-large">Add Widget</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Not sure if this is relevant but here is my Adminpanel app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from adminpanel.forms import WidgetForm
from adminpanel.models import Widget
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse,reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
class CreateWidgetView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = WidgetForm
    model = Widget

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('adminpanel:widgets')

class SettingsListView(ListView):
    model = Widget
    ordering = ['widget_order']

class DeleteWidget(LoginRequiredMixin,SelectRelatedMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Widget
    select_related = ('Widget',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('adminpanel:widget')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

Here is what is happening:
[image]

As you can see in the sidebar where is says `{{ user.username }} <p>{{ user.username }}</p>` I want that code to actually execute instead of just display...

**Edit:** Here is my index.html where I am using an `{% include %}` to inject widget_list_inner.html (shown above)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        {% include "adminpanel/widget_list_inner.html" %}
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    {% for colorset in colorset_list %}
            <div class="colorset-info">
                <h3 class="set-name">{{ colorset.name }}</h3>
                    <p class="author accent-text">Author: {{ colorset.user }}</p>

                    {% if user.is_authenticated and colorset.user == user %}
                        <a class="auth-user-options" href="{% url 'colorsets:delete' pk=colorset.pk %}">Delete</a>
                    {% endif %}
            </div>
            <table class="colorset">
                <tr>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_one }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_two }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_three }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_four }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_five }}">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_one }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_two }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_three }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_four }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_five }}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you add the code of the sidebar template? Where the {{ user.username }} is located

Comment: @KarimNGorjux Adminpanel app widget_list_inner.html is the html that creates the sidebar with a for loop that checks the model for instances. I have an `{% include %}` tag on my index.html if you wanna see that?

Answer (score 0):

use `{{request.user.username}}`, the reason?, you have to be specific about what are you asking, so you are making a request and  of that request the actual user

Comment: Your right I didn't do that right but it still doesn't display what that code does, just the code itself as text.

Comment: Adminpanel app widget_list_inner.html is the html that creates the sidebar with a for loop that checks the model for instances. I have an {% include %} tag on my index.html if you wanna see that?

Comment: only the specific part

Comment: Just added index.html